# Interpreting interaction effects in probit regression model

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, interaction, probit

I have run a probit regression model with one 2-way interaction and am having trouble interpreting the results.  Both variables are categorical and so one level of `Job.Sector` and one level of `Name.Origin` are included in the intercept.

How do I go about interpreting the results?

The formula of the model is:

```
m1 <- glm(Success~Name.Origin*Job.Sector, family=binomial(link="probit"), x=TRUE)

                                         effect   error  t.value p.value
(Intercept)                             0.00000 0.04557  0.00000 1.00000
Name.OriginArab                        -0.27929 0.05220 -5.35014 0.00000
Name.OriginForeign                     -0.17892 0.05281 -3.38792 0.00073
Job.SectorAdmin                        -0.15071 0.03764 -4.00377 0.00007
Job.SectorHR                           -0.14825 0.03790 -3.91132 0.00010
Job.SectorIT                           -0.13218 0.04077 -3.24170 0.00123
Job.SectorMarketing                    -0.17355 0.03451 -5.02854 0.00000
Job.SectorSales                        -0.07103 0.05130 -1.38454 0.16654
Name.OriginArab:Job.SectorAdmin         0.12064 0.16450  0.73336 0.46353
Name.OriginForeign:Job.SectorAdmin      0.21264 0.14636  1.45283 0.14662
Name.OriginArab:Job.SectorHR            0.24272 0.17208  1.41051 0.15873
Name.OriginForeign:Job.SectorHR         0.18335 0.14422  1.27132 0.20394
Name.OriginArab:Job.SectorIT            0.28284 0.16756  1.68795 0.09177
Name.OriginForeign:Job.SectorIT         0.16627 0.13883  1.19763 0.23137
Name.OriginArab:Job.SectorMarketing     0.24382 0.17768  1.37225 0.17033
Name.OriginForeign:Job.SectorMarketing -0.00262 0.11643 -0.02253 0.98203
Name.OriginArab:Job.SectorSales         0.40722 0.15553  2.61828 0.00899
Name.OriginForeign:Job.SectorSales      0.20833 0.13679  1.52302 0.12811
```

Comment: Your formula doesn't make sense to me. It seems like you also having some syntax errors there.

Comment: @DavidArenburg you are correct! I have edited it now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to interpret these results in any direct way.  You presumably want to know if there is an interaction.  You can test this by fitting a nested model without the interaction term.  That is:

```
m2 <- glm(Success~Name.Origin+Job.Sector, family=binomial(link="probit"), x=TRUE)
anova(m2, m1, test="LRT")
```

If the interaction is significant, or you believe it is important to take into account either way, then you would interpret the simple effects.  That is, look at how `Success` differs by `Name.Origin` within each `Job.Sector` individually (or how `JS` differs within `NO`, depending on whichever makes more sense in the context of your study).

If the interaction is not significant and you really don't believe it (i.e., your p-value isn't just above the threshold), then use interpret the reduced model.  Because you have multiple level factor variables, you would still need to fit and test nested models (dropping one or the other variable) to test the variable as a whole.  That is, you do not want to interpret the reported t-tests / p-values in the output.

Regarding how to interpret the point estimates of the effects in your output, it may be easier to transform them into predicted probabilities.  Remember that you have a probit link function, so you need to invert that.  The probit is giving you the additive shift in the quantile of a standard normal distribution.  Thus, you calculate the probability by determining the quantile you want and passing it through the standard normal CDF to get the probability.  Remember also that the intercept is the appropriate quantile for the reference levels and the other effect estimates are the differences between that quantile and the quantile appropriate for the specified level.  To demonstrate using the first two lines of your results:

```
  ## for the reference levels:
pnorm(0.00000)   # [1] 0.5
  ## for `Name.OriginArab` at the reference level of `Job.Sector`:
pnorm(-0.27929)  # [1] 0.3900111
```